# ObjectInputStream - StreamCorruptedException:unexpected end of block data

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, java-io, objectinputstream

I have a server and client applications.

1. The client and server are in the same machine.
2. The client and server are using same java version.
3. I'm using  ObjectOutputstream /objectInputStream to write and read
   the objects
4. The transmitted object is notbeing modified while  writing

the code :

```
mySocketClient.getOos().writeObject((replyobject));
mySocketClient.getOos().flush();
mySocketClient.getOos().reset();
```

Reading Code :

```
objectInputStream.readObject();
```

The application is working good but randomly I have the below exception

```
 java.io.StreamCorruptedException: unexpected end of block data
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
```

What might be causing this?

Comment: Do you know on which line does it throw the exception? while reading or writing?

Comment: while reading  ( objectInputStream.readObject();)

Comment: Most likely, the stream has been closed while reading the object. With socket streams, that can happen all the time (e.g. timeout elapsed). Just treat it as any other I/O error as network connections *are* unreliable…

Comment: Can you explain why you need to do a `reset()` ? What happens if you don't?

Comment: @Holger That would cause an `EOFException`.